# Integral of a delta function

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

How can I calculate the integral of the form,
\begin{equation}
I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \,\delta\left(b-\sqrt{x^2+a}\right) ,
\end{equation}
assuming positive values for $a$?

Comment: Just apply the formula for $\delta(f(x))$, where $f$ has only simple zeros:
$$\delta(f(x)) = \sum_{x_i: f(x_i) = 0} \frac {\delta(x - x_i)} {|f'(x_i)|}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the definition of the Delta of a function:

$$\delta[f(x)] = \sum_R \frac{\delta(x - x_R)}{|f'(x_R)|}$$

Where the sum runs all over the $R$ that are, the roots of $f(x)$.

In your case it's simple to see that the roots are

$$x_R = \pm \sqrt{b^2-a}$$

Whence

$$\delta\left(b - \sqrt{x^2+a}\right) = \frac{\delta(x + \sqrt{b^2-a}) + \delta(x - \sqrt{b^2-a})}{\frac{\sqrt{b^2-a}}{\sqrt{b^2}}}$$

If you assume $b >0$ you can simplify the above expression into

$$b \frac{\delta(x - \sqrt{b^2-a}) + \delta(x + \sqrt{b^2-a})}{\sqrt{b^2-a}}$$

The integral now is trivial since you just need to apply the well know rules of Dirac Delta integration.

Comment: If I put `a=0`, `b=1` to integral for OP,Maple says:`0`,Mathematica:`2`. If I  solve yours  trivial integral Maple and Mathematica says: `-1`.
I'm confused?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk When $a = 0$ and $b = 1$ you simply obtain $2$, which is correct. I forgot a piece (a root). And also there is the MODULUS, which I forgot, which turns everything into positive. FIXED.

Comment: Thank you very much.     (1+).

Comment: I think this should be explicitly written as zero for $b < \sqrt a$, otherwise you have to define things like $\delta(x - i)$.

Comment: @Maxim True too!